# i18n (internationalization) in Fuel Views

Tags: php, view, internationalization, fuelphp

What's the best/suggested way to handle i18n (internationalization) strings in views for Fuel PHP? I'm unable to find any references to this in the docs and am considering going with [gettext](http://theclimber.fritalk.com/post/2009/09/16/i18n-gettext-for-your-PHP-application). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the lang class](http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/lang.html), you can use it to load the language file you need. 
An example  of code:

**example.php**

```
return array(
    'hello' => 'Hello :name',
    'something'=> 'something :name!',
    'test'=> array(
        'hello' => 'Hello', 
        'something' => 'Plop'
    )
);
```

**your file**

```
// Will load the file "example.php" into the "var" variable
Lang::load('example', 'var');

// Get the variable "something"
$this->output = Lang::get('var.test.something');
```

You can create differente language file, like "en, it" or more, and dinamically load the file based on user's local settings.

Comment: One refinement from the logs is to use Lang::get('var.test.something') as Lang::line() is deprecated. There's also the __() procedural helper. http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/lang.html

Comment: Mmm, I was searching the "Load::get" in the docs but I didn't find it. Is it a modification present in the depelopment branch?

Comment: Oh my God, my page didn't load so I read only until the end of loaded content -_-... Thanks